# Load SQL Server Database into memory with Python

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I have to do a lot of querys to a big SQL server database and the process is very slow.

I can do something like

```
import pyodbc

#database connection
tsql = "SELECT * FROM table1"
with cursor.execute(tsql):
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

But how can I do stuff like SELECT specific rows after it's loaded in memory? Because I have a lot of queries that depends of other queries and I think it's not very efficient iterate of thousands of rows to filter specific data so I think there might be a better approach to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use pandas library to do the in-memory tabular manipulations.

Answer (score 1):

If you truly have a "big SQL server database" then you don't want to load entire tables into memory. Instead, for each task just load the columns of interest from the relevant rows using standard SQL methods, e.g.,

```
crsr.execute("SELECT firstname, lastname FROM table1 WHERE country = 'Canada'")
rows = crsr.fetchall()
```

If you need information from several related tables then search the web for basic SQL tutorials that describe how to use the `JOIN` keyword to accomplish that.